# Splitting a string with "\" in Android

Tags: java, android, string, split

I am trying to split  a string  with "\" but its not working for me, the string contains alpha numeric data and some Japaneses characters..

Here is the code i am trying

```
String [] folder = null;
String [] files= null;
for (int i =0; i<listFile_Names.size();i++) 
{

String  filesList = listFile_Names.get(i);
filesList = filesList.substring(1);
Log.v("Fullpath",filesList );
try{
String[] parts = filesList.split("\\");
folder[i] = parts[0]; 
files[i] = parts[1]; 
}
catch(Exception e){
e.printStackTrace();

}
}
for(int j=0; j< folder.length; j++)
{
Log.v("Folders", folder[j].toString());
Log.v("Files", files[j].toString());

}
```

Here is what LogCat Says

```
06-11 11:19:03.300: V/Fullpath(14600): A40-002(D155AX-8_DUAL仕様ﾁｪｯｸｼｰﾄ)\sheet001.html
06-11 11:19:03.300: W/System.err(14600): java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Unrecognized backslash escape sequence in pattern near index 1:
06-11 11:19:03.300: W/System.err(14600): \
06-11 11:19:03.300: W/System.err(14600):  ^
06-11 11:19:03.300: W/System.err(14600):    at java.util.regex.Pattern.compileImpl(Native Method)
06-11 11:19:03.300: W/System.err(14600):    at java.util.regex.Pattern.compile(Pattern.java:400)
06-11 11:19:03.300: W/System.err(14600):    at java.util.regex.Pattern.<init>(Pattern.java:383)
06-11 11:19:03.300: W/System.err(14600):    at java.util.regex.Pattern.compile(Pattern.java:374)
06-11 11:19:03.300: W/System.err(14600):    at java.lang.String.split(String.java:1842)
06-11 11:19:03.300: W/System.err(14600):    at java.lang.String.split(String.java:1823)
06-11 11:19:03.300: W/System.err(14600):    at jp.co.komatsu.android.xlez.webservice.AsynTaskGetUpdatedFiles.doInBackground(AsynTaskGetUpdatedFiles.java:202)
```

Comment: I believe you need to do 4 backslashes, each one of the 2 you are trying to represent needs to be escaped.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Since the backslash has an special meaning in *regex* you have to escape it twice:

```
String[] parts = filesList.split("\\\\");
```

This is because Java interprets the string literal `\\` as `\`. You can easily see this executing this code:

```
String s = "123\\";
System.out.println(s); // Output: 123\
```

Answer (score 2):

`filesList.split("\\");`

should be

`filesList.split("\\\\");`

Comment: should be filesList.split("\\\\"); ryt?

Comment: I got an error (Java 7): *String literal is not properly closed by a double-quote*

Comment: @NithinCVpoyyil. yeah...sorry. typo mistake.

Answer (score 2):

I believe you need to do 4 backslashes, each one of the 2 you are trying to represent needs to be escaped.

```
String[] arrA = str.split("\\\\");
```

Answer (score 0):

Below will get you **File Name**

```
int idx = filesList.replaceAll("\\", "/").lastIndexOf("/");
String fileNameWithExtn =  idx >= 0 ? filesList.substring(idx + 1) : fileName;
```

To remove the file Extension and get only **File Path**, similarly

```
idx = fileNameWithExtn .lastIndexOf(".");
String filename = idx >= 0 ? fileNameWithExtn.substring(0,idx) : fileNameWithExtn ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with pattern ,

```
String[] input = { "320/10.50/Dec 11 2002/39.95",
        "110-4.25-Dec 15 2002-39.95",
        "8%54.00%Dec 4 2002%0" };

    public SplitData() {
        for (int i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
            String[] piece = input[i].split("[-/%]");
            for (int j = 0; j < piece.length; j++)
                System.out.print(piece[j] + "\t");
            System.out.print("\n");
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

if you wanna replace only one standed backslash try this one.

```
String url = "http://192.168.1.5:8080\smth";
if (url .contains("\\")){
  url = url .replaceAll("\\\\", "/");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Kotlin:

```
val spKt = "\\"
```

But in Java:

```
String sp = "\\\\"
```

If you do this in Java:

```
str.split(spKt);
```

It will be error!!!

> java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Unrecognized backslash escape sequence in pattern near ...

So please distinguish them:

```
// Kotlin
str.split(spKt)

// Java
str.split(sp)
```